# Why is there an extra <E> in this generic method?

Tags: java, generics, methods

I learned java generics some time ago, but now I'm learning collections and found some code that I don't understand. Here is the code:

```
static <E> List<E> nCopies(int n, E value)
```

It is from class `java.util.Collections`.

My question is why there is:

```
<E> List<E>
```

and not only

```
List<E>
```

Obviously I am missing something, can someone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `<E> List<E>`, the first `<E>` denotes that `E` is a *type parameter*. If you hadn't specified it, then Java would think the `E` in `E value` referred to an actual class named `E`, and ask you to import it. See [generic methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html).

Comment: Why this couldn't be written like: `static List<E> nCopies(int n, <E> value)`. Was there any problem for designers of Java programming language to do this way, like I wrote above? For me it's more clear way of representing generic variable.

Comment: One reason might be in case you had multiple parameters with type `<E extends F>` it would get repetitive; better to just put it up front and then just use `<E>` everywhere.

Answer (score 13):

You use the `<E>` to typify the method you are defining.

The most common example of generics is to have a typified class like this:

```java
public class SomeClass<E> {
    ...
}
```

Then, when you are creating a new object of that class you define the type directly like this:

```java
new SomeClass<String>();
```

That way any method in that class that refers to `<E>`, will treat `<E>` as a String, for that instance.

Now consider a static method (which is not bound to any particular instance of a class), in order to typify that method you have use another kind of typification which applies to methods, like this:

```java
static <E> List<E> nCopies(int n, E value)
```

You use the `<E>` before the return type to say "this particular method will consider some E when it executes". What `<E>` will be is decided when you invoke the method:

```java
nCopies(3, "a");
```

In this example `<E>` will be a String, so the return type will be a `List<String>`.

Finally, you can even mix them both:

```java
public class SomeClass<E> {
    public <F> void doSomething(E e, F f) {
        ...
    }
}
```

In this case, if you have an instance of SomeClass, the E in the doSomething method will always be String (for that instance), but the F can be anything you want it to be.

Answer (score 5):

The `<E>` is required to tell the compiler that you intend to use `E` as a type parameter, the same way you do when you make a generic class (e.g. `public interface List<E>`).

Since there is no rule (only conventions) on interface or class names being more than one character, and no rule (only conventions) that type parameter names have to be one character, the compiler would not know you intended it to be a type parameter rather than a concrete class name.

### Edit

A lot of people have been saying this is directly related to static methods.  That is not true.  You can have an instance method that is generic on its own type parameters as well (though typically, the type parameters will be related to the class type parameters).

Here's an example of where you could have this:

```
public class MyList<E> {

    public <N super E> MyList<N> createCopy() {
        //...
    }
}
```

This method would allow you to create a copy of the list but not restrain you to using the same type as the list you have, but rather allowing you to use a supertype.  For example:

```
MyList<Integer> integers = createList(1, 2, 5);
MyList<Number> numbers = integers.createCopy();
```

Answer (score 2):

`List<E>` is the *return type* for the method whereas `<E>` is the type being passed in (This is inferred by the compiler from what is being passed as `E value`).

```
static <E> List<E> someMethod(E myObject)
{
    E objectOfMyType = myObject;
    List<E> myList = new ArrayList<E>();
    ...
    return myList; 
}
```

This would be called as:

```
MyObject o = new MyObject();
List<MyObject> myList = SomeClass.someMethod(o);
```

IMHO the syntax for methods is kinda goofy, but there you have it. The relavent Oracle tutorial is here:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Comment: I don't understand why this is in front of List<E>. I understand that value is of type E, but <E> in front of List<E> confuses me. Thanks on answer.

Comment: @Иван, it is the declaration of the type argument.  This is analogous to how you declare normal parameters in a method, like `String myStringArg`.  If, for example, you had two type parameters, it might look like `<E, TArg2>` rather than merely `<E>`.

Comment: Again, not because it's static, but because it's generic.

Comment: @Mark, agreed -- what is goofy is this idea of putting the generic type parameter declarations *in front* of the return type and method name, which somehow just violates some innate sense of grammar.

Comment: @Kirk: Maybe.  From my point of view it makes perfect sense to tell the compiler you're going to be using E as a type parameter *before* you start using it, not after.

Comment: @Mark - yeah, sorry - my typing got ahead of or behind my brain there, removed the word static from that sentence.

Comment: @Downvoter - care to comment? Or is my serial downvoter back?

Answer (score 1):

in simple words: to indicate that `E` is not a class. `List<E>` would be a valid return type if `E` was a class (or interface) - despite not recommended, a class can be named with a single letter (as a type variable also could be named with more letters, even using an existing class name, to confuse anyone: `static <Integer> List<Integer> method() {...}`).